# I'm using Python and I keep getting a segmentation fault like this

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a notepad and I keep getting an error in the code... Is there a problem with my code?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Instem 메모장")
root.geometry("640x480")


root.resizable(True, True) 

def create_new_file():
    print("새파일을 만듭니다.")

menu = Menu(root)

menu_file = Menu(menu, tearoff=0)
menu_file.add_command(label="파일", command=create_new_file)



menu.add_cascade(label="메뉴", menu=menu)

root.config(menu=menu)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: There is no problem with your code. But, you need to change `menu.add_cascade(label="메뉴", menu=menu)` -> `menu.add_cascade(label="메뉴", menu=menu_file)`

Comment: Typically, any bug that causes a segfault is going to be very specific to not your code, but to which platform you're running on and how you installed Python. (If you're on an OS where there's a choice of GUI frameworks -- like Linux where there's both X11 and Weyland -- that kind of detail should be given too).

Comment: That said, "an error" isn't really a detailed enough description for us to go off of. Even with a segfault, you should be able to get a stack trace (if you attach a debugger like gdb to the Python interpreter). Similarly, if your Python interpreter is doing a core dump, you can use a debugger to get a stack trace out of that core dump. (You might need to install debug symbols to get actual line numbers &c, but even just knowing function names is better than nothing).